# remove button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm going to add a custom angular directive which contains a button inside to delete itself.

My Problem is by clicking the button `removeMe` it is not able to delete an item from the array. Any idea what is wrong?

html:

```
<button type="button" data-ng-click="main.addNew()">Add new!</button>
<div id="container">
    <sample id="$index" list="main.list" data-ng-repeat="item in main.list"></sample>
</div>
```

directive template:

```
<div id="">
  <button type="button" ng-click="removeMe()">Remove Me</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('TestApp', [])



.controller('MainController', function () {
    var main = this;
    main.list = [];
   main.addNew = function addNew() {
     main.list.push({id:'sdgsgs'});
   }
})

.directive('sample', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {list: '=', id:'='},
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.info(scope.list);
      console.info(scope.id);
      scope.removeMe = function removeMe() {
        scope.list.slice(scope.id, 1);
        console.info(scope.list);
      }
    },
    controller: function() {
        console.log("ctrl");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: ["`slice` does not alter. It returns a shallow copy of elements from the original array."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: @Super I added the plunker for demo please check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey it's simple you are using slice instead of splice on array.

**An important aspect of slice is that it does not change the array which invokes it**

Use Splice instead of slice :)

```
scope.list.splice(scope.id, 1);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JXSn9JjLlOTS3GYgSfrn?p=preview)